# SharePoint 2013 Search not finding Site Column when creating a Custom Managed Property Mapping

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-search

I have created a Site Column, "About Customer" (Text). I am trying to create a Custom Managed Property but when I click to Add a mapping, My custom site column can not be found, no matter what I search for. Here is what I have tried so far:

- Added the column to a list and populated it with sample data
- Reset the search index then ran a full crawl
- Checked the Search Logs to verify that the List has been crawled

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: You mean the crawled property is nowhere to be found?

Comment: No i'm trying to create the managed property, but when I click on 'Add Mapping' and search for the Site Column, its not showing up at all. It usually shows up as 'ows_ColumnName'.

Answer (score 2):

Search for your Crawled Property and make note of the Data Type. (Also in SharePoint 2013 if you used a Site Column you may see your column twice, once for the crawl and once for the automatically created crawled and managed property pair.)

When you create your Managed Property, before you click "Add Mapping", ensure that you have selected the right data type for your Managed Property to match your Crawled Property.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. The site column is a text field, and I have text selected when i'm searching for the mapping. Nothing is being found.

Comment: Single line or multiple?

Comment: Single Line Text Field

Comment: So after a FULL Crawl of the content you cannot find the Crawled Property?

Comment: Correct, after resetting the index then performing a Full Crawl, the property is not showing up.

Comment: Resetting the index has no impact on Crawled Properties. SharePoint list columns should just show up. Can you tell me what the exact field name is? Are you certain that the list is being indexed?

Comment: The column name is 'test'. The url for the list shows up in the crawl log.

Comment: So you are looking for ows_test in crawled properties. Do the individual items from the list show up in the crawl log?

Answer (score 0):

Mine did not show up until I had actually used the column in my document library.  So if my column was "Type of Document," I set one file to "Report," did a crawl and it then showed up.

Answer (score -1):

When you add the mapping for the new property make sure you check the box for Searchable.

Edit: AND Retrievable.

Comment: This does not answer his question. He is asking that the site column he has created does not show up in the crawled properties and not as a managed property.